# Converting Opencart .tpl into .twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am currently trying to add some code to Twig file that I already use with PHP.
Made some changes based on https://twig.symfony.com/ but still can't get it work properly. 
Here is the `.tpl` file that uses php:

```
<?php foreach (array('catalog'=>'frontend', 'admin'=>'backend') as $k=>$v ) { ?>
    <label class="btn btn-default <?php if($interface==$k){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
    <input type="radio" name="interface" value="<?php e($k); ?>" autocomplete="off" <?php if($interface=="$k"){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> <?php e(${'tab_'.$v}); ?>
    </label>
?>
```

into this:

```
{% for k,v in array_path %}
catalog: {{frontend}}
admin: {{ backend }}
<label class="btn btn-default  {% if interface == k %} {{ active }} {% endif %} >
    <input type="radio" name="interface" value="{{ k }}" autocomplete="off" {% if interface == k %} {{ checked }} {% endif %}> {{tab_.v}}
</label>
```

and another `expression`:

```
<?php e($page == '_main_lang_file' ? $text_main_lang_file : $page); ?> 
<?php 
    echo (isset($translations[$l['directory']]) && $translations[$l['directory']] != '') ? 
    hs($translations[$l['directory']]) : '<span class="notTranslatedSpan text-danger">'.h($text_not_translated).'</span>';
?>
```

into this:

```
{{ page == '_main_lang_file' ? text_main_lang_file : page }}
{% translations l.directory && translations l.directory != '') ? 
    hs translations l.directory : '<span class="notTranslatedSpan text-danger">'.h text_not_translated'</span>'} %}
```

But I can't understand what exactly should do to make it work.

Comment: You can convert your TPL/PHP in to Twig code here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/php-to-twig here, is online PHP to twig converter ( online TPL to twig converter )

Answer (score 0):

Free resources:

1 openconverter.io - online converter, works only in some cases.

2 https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29835 - Twig Manager (add .twig support for your Opencart 2.x) - use twig theme on opencart versions 2.x.

3 https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31589 - OpenCart Template Switcher.

Quote: This module, when enabled, causes OpenCart to automatically detect the correct template engine depending on a template file extension (e.g. '.tpl', '.twig', '.smarty' etc).

Extensions and web themes can now use both PHP-templates and Twig-templates. This allows developers to easily port old OC 2.x web themes with PHP templates (*.tpl files) to the new OC 3.0.x releases.

Answer (score -1):

Your Twig syntax might be having some problems.
If you understand how previous OpenCart versions work check out these [examples](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Upgrading-themes-from-2.3-to-3.0).